# File permissions issue with webserver and ftp server

Tags: permissions, ftp

I have a question concerning permissions.

I'm running lighttpd and a ftp server.

I want to add a ftp user that is able to upload files to /var/www, which then are viewable in a browser.

What is the safest way to set this up (apart from not using ftp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usermod -a -G ftp user
chown -R :ftp /var/www/html
chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```